# Generate big prime numbers for RSA encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, encryption, rsa, primes

What should I do to generate big prime numbers for RSA?

As you know, we need to big prime numbers to make private and public keys for RSA encryption algorithm.

If I want to do it by any sieve algorithms,it take lot of time.
What is the best way?

Comment: Check if (2**n - 1) is prime for increasing values of n.

Comment: I really hope this is homework—there are a lot of subtleties in obtaining a secure RSA implementation.

Comment: @Per Blakh:|,really it's not home work,it's only my trying to develop free Open Source project.

Comment: See how the bn subsystem of OpenSSL does it: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_generate_prime.html

Comment: @Gilbert: This is a bad idea, products of such numbers can be factored in polynomial time.

Comment: @Moein7tl Open Souce does not need to be secure? What kind of project are you creating that you cannot use another open source library to do this? Can't you just lift code from a permisive licensed library otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using a library for crypto routines.  There are several, and they are fraught with subtle problems hopefully most of which are fixed in the existing implementations, and yet to be fixed in a new implementation.

However, I've played around with generating primes using Python and GMP:

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/huge-prime/trunk/

In short, trial division is best for small numbers, Miller-Rabin is good as a quick filter/test for a little larger numbers but you sometimes still end up using trial division to get guaranteed primes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Miller Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) probable prime test (more correctly a *compositeness* test), is commonly used for industrial strength primes. There are methods to generate *provable* primes, like Maurer's algorithm.

An excellent resource on the theory and implementation of prime generation is [here](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make some large primes you could write a program in python using the pycrypto module. This posting will be helpful [Using RSA in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504955/using-rsa-in-python)

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
RSAkey = RSA.generate(1024)
print getattr(RSAkey.key, 'n')
print getattr(RSAkey.key, 'p')
print getattr(RSAkey.key, 'q')
```